# jQuery clone table row in form does not submit cloned fields

Tags: php, jquery

Below is a simplified example that demonstrates the problem I am having. One hundred percent of code is posted below.

Three files work together: testa.php, testb.php, and testc.js. (FWIW, testa.php could function as the index.php, but this is just a demo)

---

OVERVIEW:

TESTA.PHP

- When user clicks anchor tag, sends value to testb.php
- Receives ajax response from testb.php into div #reportstable, within FORM structure
- Form is submitted to itself, so it prints $_POST data  -

TESTB.PHP

- receives value from TESTA.PHP, via ajax
- outputs table that corresponds to received values
- (In this example, I removed how received value is used, but still retained this structure as it affects the jQuery in testc.js)

TESTC.JS

- the jQuery that makes it (partially) work

---

**PROBLEM 1: If user adds more than one "document" (i.e. row), only data for the last document appears in the POST data.**.

**PROBLEM2: DocTitle and FileName IDs (dt1, fn1) are not POSTED as they appear in the DOM. In the DOM, their IDs are incremented properly (dt11, dt12, dt13, etc) but when POSTed only one comes through and it has not been incremented.** (Use firebug to inspect table elements after adding a couple of documents.

**PROBLEM3: First click doesn't "take" when clicking the "choose file" anchor when adding a new document.** Any thoughts on this one?

---

TESTA.PHP

```
<?php   
    If (empty($_POST)===false) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';
        die();
    }
?>
<html><body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-custom-file-input.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="testc.js"></script>
<br />

Project*:<br />
<a href="#" id="project_pick">Click Me</a>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="reportstable">
    </div>
</form>

</body></html>
```

---

TESTB.PHP

```
<?php
    $project_id = $_POST['project_id'];

    if ($project_id == 5) {
        echo '
            <table id="DocTable">
                <tr>
                    <th width="150">Document Title</th>
                    <th width="150">File Name</th>
                </tr>
                <tr name="tr2" id="tr2" style="display:none;">
                    <td><input type="text" name="dt1" id="dt1"></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="fn1" id="fn1">
                        <span id="sp1"><a href="#" id="ah1">choose file</a><span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <a href="#" id="add_row">add document</a><br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_it" value="Submit">
        ';
    }
```

---

TESTC.JS

```
$(function(){

var count = 1;
//*******************************************************************    
$('#project_pick').click(function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testb.php",
        data: "project_id=5",
        success:function(data){
            $('#reportstable').html(data);
        }
    });
});
//*******************************************************************    
$(document).on('click','#ah11',function() {
    $(this).file().choose(function(e, input) {
        $('#fn11').val(input.val());
        $('#sp11').html(input.val());
        $('#sp11').css('color','grey');
    });
});
//*******************************************************************    
$(document).on('click','#ah12',function() {
    $(this).file().choose(function(e, input) {
        $('#fn12').val(input.val());
        $('#sp12').html(input.val());
        $('#sp12').css('color','grey');
    });
});
//*******************************************************************    
$(document).on('click','#ah13',function() {
    $(this).file().choose(function(e, input) {
        $('#fn13').val(input.val());
        $('#sp13').html(input.val());
        $('#sp13').css('color','grey');
    });
});
//*******************************************************************    
$(document).on('click', '#add_row', function() {
    $("table#DocTable tr:nth-child(2)")
        .clone()
        .show()
        .find("a, input, span, tr").each(function() {
            $(this)
                .val('')
                .attr('id', function(_, id) {
                    return id + count;
                    });
        })
        .end()
        .appendTo("table");

    count++;
    if (count == 4) {
        $('#add_row').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}); //end fn add_row
//*******************************************************************    
$(document).on('click', '#submit_it', function() {
    alert('This will be submitted now');
});
//*******************************************************************
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in your javascript that you are changing the values of the `id` attribute only. However, when you post a form, the `id` attribute is irrelevant and not posted, you need the `name` attribute instead.

So where you are changing id's, you really should be changing names (and id's to if you really need them as they need to be unique).

However, a far easier solution would be to use arrays for names, like:

```
<input type="text" name="dt[]">
```

If you copy / clone elements with these names and post the form, you will get an array in your `$_POST['dt']`.

Comment: Could the solution be that straight-forward? (This is webdev; I'm a relative newbie; of course it could). Thanks Jeroen, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @gibberish I'm pretty sure it is :-)

Comment: Right. Well, now I'm sure too. Works like a charm, THANKS. BTW, any thoughts on the "first click doesn't take" problem when clicking the "choose file" anchor? Do you see the problem I'm describing with that element?

Comment: @gibberish You have posted plenty of code, it would be helpful if you could narrow it down to just the relevant functions / code but that would probably not work in this question.

Comment: Yes, I agree completely. The question took a tediously long time to compose. My problem was not understanding the subject well enough to narrow it down. My daily lament: I understand that we all must start programming somewhere, but why did I have to start at the bottom?

Comment: @gibberish To answer your question, it seems the click handler is attached to id `ah11` but in your php you echo out an element with `ah1` and there does not seem to be a javascript click handler for that element in your code.

Comment: That does not appear to solve it (at least, I can't get it to work). Although I echo out <code>ah1</code>, that row is invisible. The element being clicked on would have an id of <code>ah11</code>, and that handler does exist.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I did try adding a click handler for ah1 to the .js, but that didn't remedy the problem.